# PHP Form - Format Echo Statement Output

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm working on a php5 form.
Here's the function code:

```
function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "<div style ='background-color:green;font:22px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ff0000'>We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />
These errors appear below.<br /><br /></div>";

        echo "<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "<div style ='background-color:green;font:22px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ff0000'>Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br /></div>";

        die();

    }
```

The first and third echo statement output html format, but how do I get the middle $error statement to output pretty html?

Answer (score 1):

soemthing like this:

```
 echo "<div style ='background-color:red;'>".$error."</div>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

function died($error) {
echo <<< EOF
<div style ='background-color:green;font:22px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ff0000'>We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.<br /><br />
These errors appear below.<br /><br /></div>
<br /><br />
$error.<br /><br />
<div style ='background-color:green;font:22px Arial,tahoma,sans-serif;color:#ff0000'>Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br /></div>
EOF;
die();
}

?>
```